# why is this code removing the file instead of renaming it?

Tags: python

I want to rename report.json but it is removing the file instead

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import json



path =Path( r'C:\Users\Sajid\Desktop\cuckoo (3)\cuckoo\storage\analyses\3\reports')
filename = os.path.join(path,"report.json")
with open(filename) as json_file:
    data=json.load(json_file)
    var=(data['target']['file']['md5'])
    print(var)
    json_file.close()
    os.rename(filename,var)
```

I expect this code to rename the file and not delete it

Comment: you used with, and renamed inside the block. i suspect that can be an issue?

Comment: un-indent the os.rename command should do it

Comment: `pathlib` does not exist on Python 2.x: `ImportError: No module named pathlib`

Comment: FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'C:\\Users\\Sajid\\Desktop\\cuckoo (1)\\cuckoo\\storage\\analyses\\3\\reports\\report.json' -> '293239c738433b30ebd6e73d9415b1cc' (after un-indent)

Comment: @QuratulainSajid: That's not actually caused by the dedent, it's just because you were running for the second time, and you weren't actually deleting files in the first place, just moving them to the wrong place. My answer provides fixes for both problems (though using `os.rename` is not a problem if the goal is to avoid overwriting an existing file on Windows).

Comment: Thankyou so much , it is working well now

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not deleting it, but moving it to your working directory (so if you launched your script from `C:\Users\Sajid`, the file would be there, not in `C:\Users\Sajid\Desktop\cuckoo (3)\cuckoo\storage\analyses\3\reports`). **Edit:** Based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56691957/why-is-this-code-removing-the-file-instead-of-renaming-it/56692030#comment99949394_56691957), this is definitely what's happening; the first time you ran your code, it moved it to your working directory (with component `cuckoo (1)`, where you probably expected it to go to the one with component `cuckoo (3)`), the second time it failed because `os.rename` won't overwrite an existing file on Windows.

Change it to combine the desired target directory with the basename of the file, a la:

```
var = os.path.join(str(path), os.path.basename(data['target']['file']['md5']))
```

so it stays in the same directory.

You're also unnecessarily closing the file twice (once explicitly, once implicitly via the `with` block termination). As it happens, the first one is necessary, but only because you kept the `rename` inside the `with` block. The simplest solution is to just remove the extra `close`, and `rename` outside the `with` block (in fact, you don't need it open after the `json.load`, so you may as well close it then):

```
with open(filename) as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
# Dedent to implicitly close file
var = os.path.join(str(path), os.path.basename(data['target']['file']['md5']))
print(var)   
os.rename(filename,var)
```

As written, you won't replace an existing file (on Windows; on UNIX-like systems, it will); if you want to silently replace the existing file everywhere, use `os.replace` instead of `os.rename`.

Comment: "On Unix, if *dst* exists and is a file, it will be replaced silently if the user has permission." https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html

Comment: @MaximeLaunois: Yeah, in this case it was pretty obvious that they were on Windows, but I've made an edit to make that 100% clear.